# How to increase MySQL connections(max_connections)?

Tags: mysql, database, sockets, database-connection

Every socket of MySQL Database will have defaults connections as 100 but I am looking for any way to increase the number of possible connections > 100 to a socket connection of MySQL Database.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If you need to increase MySQL Connections without MySQL restart do like below

```
mysql> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 100   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connections = 150;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 150   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

These settings will change at MySQL Restart.

---

For permanent changes add below line in my.cnf and restart MySQL

```
max_connections = 150
```

Comment: Thank you but may I know the maximum limit ?

Comment: what do you mean by maximum limit ?

Comment: @shekhar:- The maximum concurrent connection can be maximum range: 4,294,967,295. Check this:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections

Comment: @AbdulManaf Thank you so much. so you sure that we no need to restart MySQL DB ?

Comment: @AbdulManaf  May you help me if MySQL having more instances running how I have to move for achieving this  ?

Comment: @shekhar : You don't need to restart MySQL DB, but whenever MySQL will be restarted in future the setting will back to their default, for permanent changes add it in my.cnf and restart MySQL

Comment: If You have more than one MySQL Server, You can change it one by one

Comment: @AbdulManaf No I mean one MySQL server can have multiple instances , in such cases how can I approach ?

Comment: Tks,I change the file /etc/my.cnf adding line max_connections = x

Comment: How to decide what value to set for max_connections?

Answer (score 12):

From [Increase MySQL connection limit](http://major.io/2007/01/24/increase-mysql-connection-limit/):-

MySQL’s default configuration sets the maximum simultaneous connections to 100. If you need to increase it, you can do it fairly easily:

For MySQL 3.x:

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
set-variable = max_connections = 250
```

For MySQL 4.x and 5.x:

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
max_connections = 250
```

Restart MySQL once you’ve made the changes and verify with:

```
echo "show variables like 'max_connections';" | mysql
```

**EDIT:-**(From comments)

The maximum concurrent connection can be **maximum range: 4,294,967,295**. Check [MYSQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections)

Comment: Thank you but what are the maximum connections ?

Comment: @shekhar:- Also to add that you may run out of memory if by any chance you reach that limit. As a suggestion, you should start simple, add complexity later as required. So take a smaller figure like 100 or may be 1000

Comment: But we have to restart MySQL DB right. May you help me if MySQL having more instances running how I have to move for achieving this  ?

Comment: @shekhar:- Yes it is a good practice and also it will allow you to reflect the changes effectively!

Comment: @shekhar:- `Before increasing MySQL’s connection limit, you really owe it to yourself (and your server), to find out why you’re reaching the maximum number of connections. Over 90% of the MySQL servers that are hitting the maximum connection limit have a performance limiting issue that needs to be corrected instead.`

Comment: Please tell me , how to approach in the case of MySQL running with multiple instances ?

Comment: @RahulTripathi this may be a few years but i've hit the limit before while doing a high speed parallel gziped piped export/backup. For instance on very large sites, you will immediately hit the connection limit when backing up in a parallel form (its a sin not to gzip/zip the export, as you save up to 10x space reducing disk bottleneck by 10x), at the same time the site is live with people connecting. Taking too long to export without downtime could mean the exported data being out of sync when you have many hundreds of tables and hundreds of gigabytes of data.

Comment: @ErrorMessages use hot backup for that, no need to worry about data being out of sync.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I resolved it with MySQL workbench, as shown in the attached screenshot:

1. in the navigator (on the left side), under the section "management", click on "Status and System variables",
2. then choose "system variables" (tab at the top),
3. then search for "connection" in the search field,
4. and 5. you will see two fields that need to be adjusted to fit your needs (max_connections and mysqlx_max_connections).

Hope that helps!

[The system does not allow me to upload pictures, instead please click on this link and you can see my screenshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikU6w.png)