# is there a mysql limit as to how many people can request data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, bandwidth

I know there is a bandwidth issue with hosting, which is the total amount of resources that can be consumed by site users in a month, but what about mysql connections?

So, if I have enough bandwidth, and I have a php/mysql powered website, and on that website a menu in which each link selects and displays data from the database, is there a limit as to how many different people (computers) can click the same link at the same or around the same time to get the database data, supposing there is enough bandwidth?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [increase MySQL connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297773/increase-mysql-connections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the MySQL variable "max_connection" limits how many client connections can be opened to the MySQL server at the same time. You can check the value of this variable with:

```
show variables like "max_connections";
```

The default value is 151. You can use the `show processlist` command to see how many connections are open at the moment.

In practice, this value should be more than enough for a small site with a DB backend. If you find yourself running out of connections, more likely your queries are not optimized and taking too long or hanging.

Comment: Hm that doesn't seem like much. So what about a big site with tens of thousands of visitors on a daily basic, how do they get around this problem?

Comment: In practice, a typical DB request will take a few milliseconds at most, and same for the request to the webserver. HTTP is stateless - once a request is serviced, the connection doesn't "hang around" waiting for the slow human to move its hand and click the next link, blocking the whole webserver from responding. Instead, a different request is serviced. So 150 concurrent connections doesn't mean 150 concurrent human users.

Comment: As for scaling, since you asked: optimizing queries and code to be faster, optimizing the DB config for more throughput, serving content statically whenever possible, using a CDN to serve static content, using a caching layer like memcached or reddis, scaling out vertically (throw bigger hardware at it), scaling out horizontally (throw lots of small hardware at it and a load balancer), etc. But with tens of thousands of visitors, you don't need to worry about scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there may be limit, because that your 'enough' might be false in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no limit. The only limit may be your server's computing limits.

Comment: Basically you're saying it just comes down to bandwidth? So bandwidth might get exhausted and then more bandwidth(servers) would be needed?