# 'max_user_connections' in django web application

Tags: python, mysql, django

i have developed a Django web application for a chatbot that acts as s store's customers service.

At first i was using Sqlite3 foe my databases, i was working fine but some times it causes the (Data Base is Locked error).So, i switch to Mysql for the application backend and the other databases.

to be clear i have 5 DB all are under the user eman_saad:

1.db.

2.chating_log.

3.female_brain.

4.male_brain.

5.orderss.

But now i have this error:

```
  django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1203, "User eman_saad already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections")
```

i'ev tired increasing the max_connection using the terminal and login mysql>.
but still the error remain the same.

PS: I am using django10, Python3.5,webfaction shared server,Mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase MySQL connections(max\_connections)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297773/how-to-increase-mysql-connectionsmax-connections)

Comment: @ozgur  i'ev tried increasing the max_connection using the first solution in my macOS terminal(change it form 150 to 250) but when i run ==> python3 manage.py makemigrations i still have the same ERORR.. some said that i should create for each DB a different user

Comment: Why are you using 5 Databases anyways? 1 database is good enough for an application. Do you mean 5 tables?