# I can't call query after a while in a React Native project that uses MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, react-native, database-connection

In my project, I access the MySQL database. I can call and run queries in this database through the program. However, after a while, the called queries become dysfunctional or not called at all.

The example run of the queries: [image: Query Execution Example]

When I investigated my problem, I found a solution that I needed to increase the maximum number of connections. However, even if I used it, there was no change.

I tried this code: `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 150;` from this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297773/how-to-increase-mysql-connectionsmax-connections).

The connection part via node.js:

```
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : '192.168.1.101',
  user     : 'db_manager',
  password : '...', 
  database : 'venue_recommendation'
});

const app = express();

app.get('/venues', function (req, res) {

  let sQuery = "SELECT * FROM mekanlar WHERE mekanlar.mahalle_no=\""+req.query.neig+"\" AND mekanlar.puan >="+req.query.star+" AND mekanlar.fiyat <="+req.query.price+";"

  console.log(">>>>>",sQuery)

  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if(err) throw err;

  connection.query(sQuery, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;

    res.send(results);
  });
  });
});

app.get('/Cuisines', function (req, res) {

  let sQuery = "SELECT * FROM mutfaklar;"

  console.log(">>>>>",sQuery)

  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if(err) throw err;

  connection.query(sQuery, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;

    res.send(results);
  });
  });
});
```